# Export password protected pdf from crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

How to export password protected pdf file from crystal report

Answer (score 2):

Crystal Report Viewer does not have the feature to set the password when exported into PDF.

You need to use a third party control.

For more details, see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/613d5ee6-b044-4af8-8e5a-cfcdade47e4b/